# The value of the following limitation

Tags: limits

What is the value of the following limitation ($a$ is a positive real number)?  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{a^{1/n}}{n+1}+\frac{a^{2/n}}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+...+\frac{a^{n/n}}{n+\frac{1}{n}}\right)$$

1)$\dfrac{1}{\ln a}$

2)$\dfrac{a-1}{\ln a}$

3)$\dfrac{a}{\ln a}$

4)$\dfrac{a+1}{\ln a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

$$\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{a^{1/n} + \cdots + a^{n/n}}{n} < \frac{a^{1/n}}{n + 1} + \frac{a^{2/n}}{n + \frac{1}{2}} + \cdots + \frac{a^{n/n}}{n + \frac{1}{n}} < \frac{a^{1/n}+\cdots a^{n/n}}{n}.$$

Consider that the left- and right-hand sides contain Riemann sums of the continuous function $a^x$ over the interval $[0,1]$. Show that they converge to $\int_0^1 a^x\, dx$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the "squeeze theorem" and the formula for a geometric partial sum
 $$
\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{a^{1/n}}{n+1}+\frac{a^{2/n}}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\cdots+\frac{a^{n/n}}{n+\frac{1}{n}})
\leq \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1{n} a^{1/n}\frac{a-1}{a^{1/n}-1}
$$